# How to add an integer to a slice from Rust ndarray?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

Let me try:

```rust
let mut a: Array2<usize> = Array2::zeros((20, 20));
let z = a.slice(s![.., 1]);
z += 1;
```

which gives:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&usize>, _>`
```

Comment: https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/issues/1090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `u64` instead of `usize`, you'll succeed. See the following example:

```rust
use ndarray::{s, Array2};

pub fn foo() -> Array2<u64> {
    let mut a: Array2<u64> = Array2::zeros((20, 20));
    let z = a.slice(s![.., 1]);
    z += 1;
    z
}

pub fn bar() -> Array2<usize> {
    let mut a: Array2<usize> = Array2::zeros((20, 20));
    let z = a.slice(s![.., 1]);
    z += 1; // NOTE: Fails!
    z
}
```

[Rust playground link of this snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e47fa508cddef5df45d22ad9eb67a73d)

It's because ndarray didn't implemented the `Add` trait for `usize` type. It's implemented for `i32`, `u32`, and any other fixed sized integer types though.

Update: [I've submit a PR to fix this issue, and it has been merged.](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/1128)

###### References

- https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-Add%3CArrayBase%3CS%2C%20D%3E%3E
- https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/1128

Comment: OK. That's incredibly arbitrary?

Comment: @Alper Actually I just made a PR for you https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/1128

Comment: @Alper The PR I've submitted has been merged and this will be fixed in next ndarray release.